# OS X Lion debug problems

Tags: gdb, go

Using OS X Lion, I installed gdb 7.5.1 in /usr/local/bin/gdb. I built my go project like so:

```
go build -ldflags "-s"
```

Attempting to debug with:

```
/usr/local/bin/gdb xxx
```

Results in:

```
Reading symbols from /Users/xxxx...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked for no debugging symbols. [Debugging Go Code With Gdb](http://golang.org/doc/gdb) says:

> Pass the '-s' flag to the linker to **omit** the debug information (for example, go build -ldflags "-s" prog.go).

(My emphasis.)

Don't do that. :)

Comment: thks a lot ,my mistake...T.T